# Delimited text layer ACLED data base: I can't see all the points

Tags: point, layers

I downloaded a CSV file from the ACLED database but I am struggling to see all the points on my map.

I have over 2000 rows, so I should have 2000 points or so to showcase on my map when the longitude and Latitude are not exactly the same. However, I can only see 20 of them at the moment. My parameters seem correct, the longitude and latitude are included in the CSV and indicated in the X and Y fields, on a EPSG 4326. I have added a screenshot to make it easier for the ones that might have the answer and I have added the CSV I am working on.

Data set is here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yWLxDdG4hAhGHG87Lmo0BEr-qnR9O7DZNkQFr1VW_Z0/edit?usp=sharing

What could be the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have 23 locations. If you concatenate the latitude and longitude as text then just count that you get 23 locations and their counts. I show this below. This is creating stacked data points at those 23 locations in Palestine.  So what you are getting is sensible.

[image: Results]

Comment: Ah ! So easy,  thanks for flagging it !!

Comment: @LTNNOOR26 If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.